Playwright - waitForUrl & expect connection refused
I'm writing some tests for a project using playwright. We want to click this button, and the expected result is a connection refusal. However, I'm not sure how to express that in code.
Basically, what I have now:
await page.locator('id=submit').click();
await page.waitForURL('http://link-that-should-refuse-connection'); <-- want to test that it redirects to this URL

I didn't find the documentation incredibly helpful for me, as it just lists two errors (Time Out and WebError) and I'm not sure if those are the right ones for me.
Thanks

Your code should work. Please share a [mcve] if not. Backing up a bit, this is a rather unusual thing to want to test, so more context might be useful, since there may be a better way to achieve whatever you're trying to achieve.

If you know which text will appear on the screen when the connection is refused, you can do something like:
await expect(page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Connection Refused' })).toBeVisible();

